# Sql returning wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

As on the image, The SQL is ment to return results for a certain User ID but returns results from another UID.

```
SELECT user_games.APPID, user_games.UID, user_games.type, games_xbox.logo_small, games_other.system, games_other.logo, COALESCE( games_steam.name, games_xbox.name, games_other.name ) AS name
FROM user_games
LEFT JOIN games_steam ON user_games.APPID = games_steam.APPID
LEFT JOIN games_xbox ON user_games.APPID = games_xbox.APPID
LEFT JOIN games_other ON user_games.APPID = games_other.APPID
WHERE user_games.UID = "LAnXQshTItjyifF8f"
AND games_steam.name LIKE "%%"
OR games_xbox.name LIKE "%%"
OR games_other.name LIKE "%%"
GROUP BY user_games.APPID
```

Comment: There are no aggregating functions here !?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parentheses:

```
SELECT user_games.APPID, user_games.UID, user_games.type, games_xbox.logo_small, games_other.system, games_other.logo, COALESCE( games_steam.name, games_xbox.name, games_other.name ) AS name
FROM user_games
LEFT JOIN games_steam ON user_games.APPID = games_steam.APPID
LEFT JOIN games_xbox ON user_games.APPID = games_xbox.APPID
LEFT JOIN games_other ON user_games.APPID = games_other.APPID
WHERE user_games.UID = "LAnXQshTItjyifF8f"
AND (games_steam.name LIKE "%%"
  OR games_xbox.name LIKE "%%"
  OR games_other.name LIKE "%%")
GROUP BY user_games.APPID
```

Comment: Thanks, Working perfectly.

Comment: you welcome, always be careful with AND and OR in the same WHERE :)

Comment: ...and there are no aggregating functions here either

Comment: strange, I think Tristan was doing just some tests ignoring the GROUP BY